# ORACLE FORMS 5 - Insert Trigger missing?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I am have never worked with Oracle technology before. Last week i had to do some changes in very old project based on Oracle Forms 5 technology in my work.
I am used Developer 2000 for Forms and Tora for database. I did some small changes in one form, every step, which i added are OK, but the last button click show me error: 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger DBNAME.TRIGGER_NAME

Problem is, that i really dont know, where can i find trigger - DBNAME.TRIGGER_NAME.

I tried search this trigger in database - unsuccessfully.
I tried search this trigger in PL/SQL code in whole project - unsuccessfully.

How is it possible?

It could be that it is a really old technology, and software Tora / also relatively old version / instance proves triggers / I can see the structure and data, including aliases, the sequence /?

Where else should I look for?

Comment: Where you tried searching the trigger?

Comment: In whole pl/sql project code - all triggers, funcions, LOVs, In whole project DB, all tables, all sequencis, all aliases, all triggers /i dont see any trigger there/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search the trigger in DBA_TRIGGERS. If found you can easily extract the source code from DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL function.

Also you can from DBA_DEPENDENCIES where all it is referenced.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found a "missing" trigger in DBA_TRIGGERS.

Comment: You are welcome. If this helped you can u please accept the answer so that it can be useful to others too.